# Can I use a wildcard to denote subdirectories as opposed to just files in the Windows Command Prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line

I know I can use a wildcard to list the *files* in a single directory:

`dir *.java`

However, does anyone know if it is possible to denote a subdirectory with a wildcard as well?

I would like to do something like

`dir classes/*/*.java`

Where, it will list all the java files in every subdirectory beneath the classes directory.

So, if there is:

classes/cs1100/
classes/cs1200/
classes/cs1500/

It will list all the java files within these.

Note, I'm not using this specifically for the "Dir" command, but instead another command line tool that accepts a list of files.  But, if it works for Dir, it shoudl work in my other program as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `dir /s *.java`.

From `dir /?`

> /S  Displays files in specified directory and all subdirectories.

You will want to combine it with the `/b` flag which:

> /B Uses bare format (no heading information or summary).

Otherwise you get a summary and header for each sub folder rather than just a list of files.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this as follows:

open your command prompt, 
navigate to your classes directory, so your current directory is actually in classes, 
then type in the following command:

`dir /S *.java`

the /S option will tell it to recurse all sub-directories. This definitely works in `dir`. How it will port to whatever other tool you are using, I cannot say.